# Why does pureconfig not find my implicit readers?

Tags: scala, implicit, pureconfig

I use double to encode boolean value in a configuration file. PureConfig does not find a way to cast it while reading the configuration.

---

Initial question (see below for edit).

Here is some code to reproduce the behavior.

```scala
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
import pureconfig.ConfigReader
import pureconfig.generic.auto._

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(pureconfig.loadConfig[BooleanTest](ConfigFactory.parseString("a = 1")))
  }
}

case class BooleanTest(a: Boolean)

object ConfigImplicits {
  implicit val myBooleanReader: ConfigReader[Boolean] = ConfigReader[Double].map { n => n > 0}
}
```

Here, I expect my code to print an instance of `BooleanTest`.
Instead, I got a `ConvertFailure`:

```
Left(ConfigReaderFailures(ConvertFailure(WrongType(NUMBER,Set(BOOLEAN)),None,a),List()))
```

One way to fix this, is to add `import ConfigImplicits._` just before calling the `loadConfig` function.
However, as you can suppose, my code is actually part of a bigger project, and adding the `import` in the real project does not fix my error.

Do you have any hint on what can be wrong?

Kind,
Alexis.

---

### Edit:

After [comments from Thilo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56270918/why-does-pureconfig-not-find-my-implicit-readers?noredirect=1#comment99158430_56270918) it appears logic to add the `import` statement.

Below is an updated version of the code which include the `import` statement but still produce the same error...

Change the `main` function to:

```scala
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  println(ConfigUtils.loadConfig[BooleanTest]("a = 1"))
}
```

And declare a ConfigUtils object as follow:

```scala
object ConfigUtils {
  def loadConfig[A : ConfigReader](str: String) : ConfigReader.Result[A] = {
    import ConfigImplicits._
    val config = ConfigFactory.parseString(str)
    pureconfig.loadConfig[A](config)
  }
}
```

Run the code and you get the same error as previously:
`ConvertFailure(WrongType(NUMBER,Set(BOOLEAN))`

Why does `pureconfig` not use my implicit `myBooleanReader` to parse this configuration?

Kind, Alexis.

Comment: Why does adding the import in the real project not fix the error? How is it supposed to find the implicit if you do not import it?

Comment: The implicit is declared in the same file (as an implicit object inside an object). Why it does not fix the error is a real mystery !

Comment: The implicit is declared inside of `ConfigImplicits`. You want to use it inside of `Main`. These are two separate objects. Unless you do something (like an `import`) the implicit is not in scope in `Main`.

Comment: Well, this seems logical, but it does not explain why it does not work in bigger project. I will try to reproduce the bug with small code...

Comment: You have some indirection here, maybe that is the problem in your bigger project. You need a `ConfigReader[BooleanTest]`. That one is automagically created by the `auto._`. It in turn needs a `ConfigReader[Boolean]`. Without your implicit, it will just read booleans the normal way. So you need to have your implicit ready where the `ConfigReader[BooleanTest]` is created (not where it is used!).

Comment: Personally I find this setup too fragile and would generally also follow Convention over Configuration. Do not have code that converts Double into Boolean behind the scenes. Either put `true/false` into your config file (much preferred) or read it as a Double and have some `def aBoolean` on your case class to convert it. The ConfigReader should just read the file, not do weird transformations.

Comment: ... or if you really must, make a new type `BooleanDouble`. That way, at least you get compile-time errors when the implicit reader is missing (instead of the default reader for boolean and run-time errors when it sees a number instead of boolean).

Comment: You need to have your implicit visible at the call-site of `ConfigUtils.loadConfig[BooleanTest]`. Not in your `ConfigUtils`. Read up on how the `pureconfig.generic.auto._` works. Or really: Don't try to change how booleans are read. Too fragile/confusing.